# Qual tipo de Relacionamento para esse caso?

Tags: mysql, relação

Eu sou um programador iniciante em C# e gostaria de ajudar minha empresa a sair do papel, é uma Fábrica de Sorvetes.

Nós disponibilizamos `freezers` para `clientes`. Eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema que  administre os `freezers` que cada `cliente` possui. Um Cliente pode ter vários freezers de vários tipos.

**Exemplo:**

> Sorveteria do Claudinho pode ter 1 freezer vertical, 2 horizontais etc....

É uma relação 1 para N?

Tabela `Cliente` = idCLiente, nomeFantasia, Cnpj, endereco;

Tabela `Freezer` = idFreezer, modelo, voltagem, capacidade, quantidade;

Ou N para N ?

Comment: O que representa a relação Freezer x Cliente? Se for as locações correntes, um freezer não pode estar em mais de um cliente e, portanto, seria 1xN; mas se for todas as locações, um freezer pode ser locado por diferentes clientes em diferentes espaços temporais, sendo uma relação NxN.

Comment: Depende de como você vai tratar os dados... A exemplo do que o Anderson comentou acima, você também pode ter a necessidade de ter uma tabela auxiliar para ter um histórico de por quem os freezers já foram alugados, isso tudo é muito amplo e precisa de uma análise mais a fundo do que você necessita no seu sistema :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para tu entender melhor a forma de fazer esse relacionamento e fazendo uma descrição com tudo que deve estar presente no banco.

**Exemplo:**

- 1 Freezer pode ter muitos modelos, mas 1 Modelo pode ter um freezer
- 1 Cliente pode ter vários freezers, mas um freezer pode ter apenas 1 cliente.

Neste caso temos duas relações 1 para muitos.

O freezer se relaciona com modelos e se relaciona com clientes, caso seja diferente esse relacionamento, como não entendo bem a sua regra de negocio, mas por exemplo...

- 1 cliente muitos freezers e 1 freezer muitos clientes.

Nesse caso tu teria muitos para muitos do qual tu precisaria criar uma tabela especifica para esse relacionamento.

Por exemplo: `freezercliente` que seja 1 para muitos com freezer e 1 para muitos com clientes.

Preste muita atenção nessas ligações muitos para muitos uma tabela muitos para muitos devem estar relacionadas diretamente, seria impossível administrar.